# Calculadora Textual en Python no resuelve operaciones con múltiples paréntesis ni operaciones que empiezan con número negativo

Tags: python

Estoy desarrollando una calculadora textual de tipo consola en Python. Recibe del usuario operaciones en formato `([expresion] + [expresion])` y me devuelve la respuesta.
Puede calcular sumas, restas, divisiones, multiplicaciones, funciones como seno, coseno, tangente, sqr, sqroot, factorial, %, o div.
Las condiciones son:

- siempre debe recibir las operaciones entre paréntesis
- las 4 principales (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) solo funcionan si se tiene dos operandos

La cuestión es que quiero que reciba operaciones tipo `(-3 + 4)`, pero al momento de ingresarlas no me devuelve ninguna respuesta.
En cambio si le ingreso `(3 + -4)`, sí me calcula la respuesta correcta.
Obviamente si lo ingreso como `((-3) + 4)`, sí lo calcula bien, pero necesito que lo haga de la forma `(-3 + 4)`.

Por otro lado, las funciones que ingresa el usuario como `(cos 90)` o `(sqroot 4)` las calcula correctamente.
Pero si le ingreso `(cos -90)`, por ejemplo, no lo calcula.
Sin embargo si lo ingreso como `(cos (-90))`, sí lo calcula.

Además, tampoco me resuelve las operaciones si las ingreso en forma `(((3 + 4)))` y necesito que sí lo haga.

El código es el siguiente:

```
import math

def calculate(expression):
    # Check for simple expressions
    try:
        return float(expression)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    
    # Check for compound expressions
    if expression.startswith('(') and expression.endswith(')'):
        expression = expression[1:-1]
 
        if ' ' not in expression:
            return calculate(expression)
        if expression.startswith('-'):
            return -1 * calculate(expression[1:].strip())
        
        # Handle nested expressions
        left, operator, right = '', '', ''
        level = 0
        for i in range(len(expression)):
            char = expression[i]
            if char == '(':
                level += 1
            elif char == ')':
                level -= 1
            elif level == 0 and char in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
                operator = char
                left = expression[:i].strip()
                right = expression[i+1:].strip()
                if operator == '-' and left == '':
                  left = '0'
                break
        
        if operator:
            if left.startswith('(') and left.endswith(')'):
                left = calculate(left)
            if right.startswith('(') and right.endswith(')'):
                right = calculate(right)
            if operator == '+':
                return calculate(left) + calculate(right)
            elif operator == '-':
                return calculate(left) - calculate(right)
            elif operator == '*':
                return calculate(left) * calculate(right)
            elif operator == '/':
                denominator = calculate(right)
                if denominator == 0:
                    return 'ERROR! Division by zero'
                return calculate(left) / denominator
            
        # Handle function calls
        if expression.startswith('sqroot '):
            value = calculate(expression[7:].strip())
            if value < 0:
                return 'ERROR! negative square root'
            return math.sqrt(value)
        elif expression.startswith('cos '):
            value = calculate(expression[4:].strip())
            return math.cos(math.radians(value))
        elif expression.startswith('sin '):
            value = calculate(expression[4:].strip())
            return math.sin(math.radians(value))
        elif expression.startswith('tan '):
            value = calculate(expression[4:].strip())
            return math.tan(math.radians(value))
        elif expression.startswith('sqr '):
            value = calculate(expression[4:].strip())
            return value ** 2
        elif expression.startswith('factorial! '):
            value = int(expression[11:].strip())
            return math.factorial(value)
    
    # Invalid expression
    return 'ERROR! Invalid expression'

# Welcome message
print('Welcome to Text Calculator!')
print('Created by [YOUR NAME HERE]')

# Start the calculator loop
while True:
    # Wait for user input
    expression = input('calculator >> ')
    
    # Check for quit command
    if expression == 'quit':
        print('Coming out...')
        print('Thank you for using our calculator.')
        break
    
    # Calculate the expression
    result = calculate(expression)
    
    # Display the result or error message
    print('answer >>', result)
```

Comment: Creo que deberías trabajar con el análisis sintáctico y la asociatividad. Aquí tienes [una playlist al respecto](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZQftyCk7_Sdu5BFaXB_jLeJ9C78si5_3).